# R sqldf "error in statement: near "–": syntax error"

Tags: sql, r, syntax-error, where-clause, sqldf

I have the following dataset that I am using to calculate re-hospitalization within 30 days from, using SQL code within R.

```
  str(tb1)

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  35255 obs. of  56 variables:
 $ Source                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "C","E": 1 1 1 1 1 1    1     1 1 2 ...
 $ UniversalID              : int  712 123 123 123 156 189 481 ...
 $ DOB                      : Factor w/ 5491 levels "1/1/1997","1/1/1998",..: 2431 2431 2431 2431 2431 2431 2431 2431 2431 459 ...
$ Gender                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "FEMALE","MALE": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ AgeonDOS                 : int  14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 17 ...
$ RaceDescription          : Factor w/ 7 levels "Asian or Pacific Islander",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
$ ClaimType                : Factor w/ 5 levels "C","H","I","L",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
$ ClaimTypeDescription     : Factor w/ 5 levels "Home Health Claims",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ CYTDOS                   : int  2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 ...
$ FDOS                     : Factor w/ 385 levels "1/1/2014","1/10/2014",..: 350 350 350 350 350 350 350 350 350 353 ...
$ TDOS                     : Factor w/ 365 levels "1/1/2014","1/10/2014",..: 306 306 306 306 306 306 306 306 306 309 ...
```

When I run my sqldf I get the following error:

```
> readcount<-sqldf("SELECT A.UniversalID , A.TDOS, B.FDOS, A.PROC,A.seqno
+                   FROM tb1 AS A
+                  JOIN tb1 AS B 
+                 ON A.UniversalID = B.UniversalID
+                where  B.seqno = A.seqno + 1 and B.FDOS – A.TDOS between 0 and 30
+              ")
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: near "–": syntax error
```

Which I don't get if I don't include the last where clause:

```
> readcount<-sqldf("SELECT A.UniversalID , A.TDOS, B.FDOS, A.PROC,A.seqno
+                  FROM tb1 AS A
+                  JOIN tb1 AS B 
+                  ON A.UniversalID = B.UniversalID
+                   where B.seqno = A.seqno + 1
+                  ")
>
```

What's wrong with B.FDOS-A.TDOS between 0 and 30 ?

I also tried the following:

```
    > readcount<-sqldf("SELECT A.UniversalID , A.TDOS, B.FDOS, A.PROC,A.seqno
   +                   FROM tb1 AS A
   +                  JOIN tb1 AS B 
   +                 ON A.UniversalID = B.UniversalID
   +                where  B.seqno = A.seqno + 1 and DATEDIFF(A.TDOS,B.FDOS) between 0 and 30 
   +              ")
   Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: no such function: DATEDIFF
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. it worked when I put " where  B.seqno = A.seqno + 1 and (B.FDOS-A.TDOS) between 0 and 30". 
The date fields are characters.

Comment: `error in statement: near "–": syntax error` is because you are using a long dash, not a minus sign; and `error in statement: no such function: DATEDIFF` is because `DATEDIFF` is a SQL Server function, which is not one of the backends supported by `sqldf`.